# Strange Robocopy behavior in directory mirroring

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, robocopy

I use robocopy to keep some directories synchronized between two iSCSI attached arrays on a Windows Server 2012.

I have noticed strange behavior in Robocopy and have done a test. I created a script to sync only one directory and ran it at dawn 6 times in a row. By logic the first time the command was run would synchronize everything and the others would have nothing to do, just list.

However the behavior is as follows in executions 1,3 and 5 the result is one and in executions 2,4 and 6 the result is another.

See below the logs of the 6 runs.

ROBOCOPY COMMAND

```
SOURCE:      E:\FILESERVER\PROJETO-5001
DESTINATION: D:\FILESERVER-MIR\PROJETO-5001
FILES:       *.*
OPTIONS:     *.* /FFT /TEE /S /E /DCOPY:DA /COPY:DATS /SECFIX /PURGE /MIR /R:0 /W:0
```

execution 1

```
              Total    Copiada Ignorada Incompatibilidade FALHA    Extras
Diretórios:   1200     0       0        0                 0        0
Arquivos:     7906     2791    5115     0                 0        0
Bytes:        24.369g  3.321g  21.048g  0                 0        0
N.º de Vezes: 0:01:25  0:00:22                            0:00:00  0:01:02

Velocidade:    155857123 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:    8918.216 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em: domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:16:38
```

execution 2

```
              Total    Copiada Ignorada Incompatibilidade FALHA    Extras
Diretórios:   1200     0       0        0                 0        0
Arquivos:     7906     4945    2961     0                 0        0
Bytes:        24.369g  20.744g 3.625g   0                 0        0
N.º de Vezes: 0:01:22  0:00:10                            0:00:00  0:01:12

Velocidade:    2152095150 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:    123143.872 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em: domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:18:01
```

execution 3

```
             Total     Copiada Ignorada Incompatibilidade FALHA    Extras
Diretórios:   1200     0       0        0                 0        0
Arquivos:     7906     2791    5115     0                 0        0
Bytes:        24.369g  3.321g  21.048g  0                 0        0
N.º de Vezes: 0:00:45  0:00:09                            0:00:00  0:00:36

Velocidade:    387652024 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:    22181.626 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em: domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:18:47
```

execution 4

```
              Total    Copiada  Ignorada Incompatibilidade FALHA    Extras
Diretórios:   1200     0        0        0                 0        0
Arquivos:     7906     4945     2961     0                 0        0
Bytes:        24.369g  20.744g  3.625g   0                 0        0
N.º de Vezes: 0:00:56  0:00:09                             0:00:00  0:00:46

Velocidade:    2242668627 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:    128326.528 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em: domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:19:44
```

execution 5

```
              Total    Copiada Ignorada Incompatibilidade FALHA    Extras
Diretórios:   1200     0       0        0                 0        0
Arquivos:     7906     2791    5115     0                 0        0
Bytes:        24.369g  3.321g  21.048g  0                 0        0
N.º de Vezes: 0:00:45  0:00:08                            0:00:00  0:00:36

Velocidade:    398838046 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:    22821.696 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em: domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:20:30
```

execution 6

```
              Total    Copiada  Ignorada Incompatibilidade FALHA    Extras
Diretórios:   1200     0        0        0                 0        0
Arquivos:     7906     4945     2961     0                 0        0
Bytes:        24.369g  20.744g  3.625g   0                 0        0
N.º de Vezes: 0:00:56  0:00:10                             0:00:00  0:00:46

Velocidade:    2133746987 Bytes/s.
Velocidade:    122093.982 MegaBytes/min.
Finalizado em: domingo, 28 de julho de 2019 02:21:27
```

Comment: Maybe you have something else running that touches the files like a backup?

Comment: Are both volumes using the same filesystem, e.g., NTFS, ReFS, FAT32, etc.?